# Date format in email template

Tags: email, email-template, datetime

I need to format a date field in Visual Force email template so that it is of the form:

```
December 5, 2012
```

I check date format guidelines in force documentation and find this:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm

I don't think this does not give me the full range of options available.  Anyone got a link which does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here you will be needed an apex method, something like this:

```
public List<String> monthList = new List<String>{'January',
                                                 'February',
                                                 'March',
                                                 'April',
                                                 'May',
                                                 'June',
                                                 'July',
                                                 'August',
                                                 'September',
                                                 'October',
                                                 'November',
                                                 'December'};

public String getDateFormatted(Date myDate)
{
    return monthList.get(myDate.month() - 1) + ' ' + myDate.day() + ', ' + myDate.year();
}
```

**UPDATE:** for use at the visualforce page you can use following code:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date, MMMM ,d  yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!NOW()}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

See the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for all the pattern letters that can be used when formatting dates.

Comment: Can I put that in a visual force email template?

Comment: I've updated my example for the visualforce page use.

Answer (score 3):

```
TEXT(DAY(TODAY()))&" "&CASE(MONTH(TODAY()),1,"January",2,"February",3,"March",4,"April",5,"May",6,"June",7,"July",8,"August",9,"September",10,"October",11,"November","December")&" "&TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()))
```

Try this formula instead than coding .